Android Studio Sync Failed, How to Upgrade Android SDK in Ionic 2
I have an old project using Ionic2 with minimum SDK 19 and Targeted SDK 29. I want to upgrade the targeted SDK 34, I don't change any code, I only change the SDK requirement in the build.gradle, but when I want to sync the gradle project in Android Studio, I received some errors, this below is the error message.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Code_Nickholas\backup\ltc\ltc_app\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.6. Current version is 8.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\Code_Nickholas\backup\ltc\ltc_app\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-8.6-all.zip

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 20s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

If I want to upgrade the app according to the requirement I have mentioned above, what is the necessary things and steps to do? If there is extra information I need to provide, please feel free to ask. Thank you.
Upgrading old project using Ionic2 with minimum SDK 19 and Targeted SDK 29 to the minimum SDK 21 and the targeted SDK 34
